# Trying to display QImage in Qt5 with OpenGL as textures

Tags: qt, opengl

I am new to OpenGl and trying to display QImage as textures.'

This is my code for object. But its just showing an small window with no image.

```
void Window::initializeGL()
{

    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    QImage img("2.png");

    m_imgSize = img.size();

    img = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB32);

    glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_imgSize.width(), m_imgSize.height(), 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}


void Window::paintGL()

{


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, m_imgSize.width(), m_imgSize.height(), GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    update(); 

}
```

and displaying it as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setVersion(3, 2);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    Window objectWindow;
    objectWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a [mcve].  As it stands you 1) never use the `QImage` data in your texture and 2) never use the texture in any OpenGL primitives.

Comment: I tried something similar to what has been presented in the link and removed the cuda related part. So just want to display the image directly . https://www.qt.io/blog/2015/03/03/qt-weekly-28-qt-and-cuda-on-the-jetson-tk1

Comment: Rather than trying to remove the cuda related code from an existing example I think you'd be far better off looking at a [good OpenGL tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/).

Comment: The opengl tutorial you shared are  good  but I am not able to find something related to my case. I want to simply display QImage as texture.